# How to begin in alpine tours

Tags: high-altitude, alpine-touring

I know it's probably too risky to make alpine tours alone, especially when you go over glaciers. I joined [DAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Alpine_Club) to be insured while in the mountains and to be able to use the offerings like courses and **guided tours**. But they are quite expensive, I can't and don't want to do this every month.

I also **read books** about the topic but I guess book knowledge isn't enough, especially for higher risk mountain tours.

In my opinion the best would be to have a couple of **more advanced friends** who are able to teach or even know guides or groups and go with them for fun and to learn. Unfortunately I am not having this opportunity.

- What do you think is most important to learn and how should one learn?

My experience is quite low, e.g. I have no clue about knots and security. I think that I am quite **well equipped** already, although this might not be the most important to start with. From my point of view I am also quite **fit**.

---

To summarize the question I could also ask:

- When you were a beginner, who were the persons you learnt from and how did you met them?
- What did they teach you and in which order?

Comment: Mountaineering isn't one activity or one skill. It's a whole bunch of different skills, only some of which will be relevant for any given climb. A rock climbing gym is a good place to start learning some basic rope skills. Self-arrest is a crucial skill that is best learned from an experienced instructor with a good student-teacher ratio; however, you can also practice it alone and review the skills using youtube videos. Gradually try different things and increasing levels of difficulty.

Comment: @BenCrowell Yes every route is different and needs a diverse set of skills. Knowing what to do while on rock and ice are what I have to learn. I made a course last year for basic mountaineering where we tried self-arrest or learnt how to navigate. It was really cool and I'd wish to do this every weekend... So I would love to "try different things". The how's and where's are the main question I am asking here. I could call it: "When you were a beginner, who were the persons you learnt from and how did you met them? What did they teach you and in which order?".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> In my opinion the best would be to have a couple of more advanced friends who are able to teach or even know guides or groups and go with them for fun and to learn. Unfortunately I am not having this opportunity (yet?).

How that, when you are already a member of the DAV? It is first and foremost an club of mountain enthusiasts, not a provider of insurance and paid courses. The [Ortsgruppen](http://www.davplus.de/home/gruppen_abteilungen/ortsgruppen) and [Interessengruppen](http://www.davplus.de/home/gruppen_abteilungen/abteilungen) are basically just people enjoying their hobby together, and open to all DAV members. They have regular (weekly to monthly) meet-ups and are usually happy to welcome newcomers. However, they will expect you to have at least basic knowledge about things like "knots and security" before they take you on a trip - so it might be a good idea to pay for a course first, maybe after going to a meet-up and asking for advice which one would be most appropriate.

There is also an [online DAV community](https://www.dav-community.de/) where your question might yield more specific answers than here.

To make this answer more general: Try to find clubs or informal meetings of fellow mountaineers where you can meet people to learn from. Apart from the internet, stores that carry mountaineering equipment are a good place to start; the employees are often involved in the local scene or at least know about it.

Comment: Hi Michael. Thx for your answer. By pure chance I discovered just yesterday that there is something like the "Interessengruppen". There is a group for alpine tours, I will go there for sure!

Answer (score 5):

If you have the equipment already, I would go back to the book and practice using the equipment.  In the US the standard text is *[Mountaineering: Freedom of the Hills](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1594851387)*; there may be equivalents in other countries.

Basic techniques such as knots can be practiced in your home, and a bit of regular practice each day should soon make them second nature.  With a tree or strong overhead beam you can also practice ascending and descending ropes using friction knots, and with a buddy (or a bag filled with weights) you can also experiment with setting up different hauling systems.  (Don't run the rope directly over a branch; the friction will damage the tree.  Run the rope through a pulley or carabiners instead.)

The idea is to have the core skills well-practiced, so that once you're out with a buddy you can focus on when and why to apply them, rather than trying to remember how to tie a particular knot.  On a related note, it's also important to make very sure you have learned the techniques correctly.  An "eh, it looks close enough" approach can result in subtle and undesirable variations.

A good subsequent step is to poke about the Internet and look at how things go wrong.  For the US the American Alpine Club publishes *[Accidents in North American Mountaineering](http://www.americanalpineclub.org/p/anam)* each year and I expect DAV has its own publications as well.  This will help you anticipate and take steps to prevent such risks, rather than risking rediscovering them on your own.